# Importing text files from folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am using Python 3.7.
I have hundreds  text files containing stock price data in a parent folder. I want extract only the closing price column of each text file. Is there a way to extract only one column of each text file from the parent folder?

Comment: just a tiny bit more of information would help. are those .csv? .xls? or plain text, in a awkward custom format? if the files are in the parent folder, why not switch just there, and remove that from the question (as this has no relevance?)...welcome to SO!

Comment: The answer if of course yes. The exact answer depends on the file format. Is it a csv file, then use the `csv` module. If it is just fixed character positions, then just take a string slice like line[30:40]

In any case please specify the file format or show a few lines from an example file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to extract a specific line from a text file?
If so then here's your answer.

```
File = open('File_Name.txt')
Lines = File.readlines()
print(Lines[Choose])
```

Choose means what ever line you want to print out.
FYI 0 is the starting line so if you replace "Choose" with 0 you will print the first line written inside that text file.